# Django/Taggit Searching for posts when all tags and title are contained in the database

Tags: python, django, search

I am trying to make a simple search system for my website. I am using `python 3.6`, `Django 1.10.5` and `Taggit 0.22.0`. When I enter tags into the search form I want it to query the database and return any posts whose tags or title contain at least part of any tags searched.

For example: `/search/?q=random%2C+stuff`

would return:

```
Post1 {Title: "How to be funny" Tags: "Random", "isn't", "Funny"}

Post2 {Title: "How to make Stuffed Turkey" Tags: "Cooking", "Thanksgiving"}
```

## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q')

    if (query == None or not query):
        tags = Post.tags.most_common()[:10]
        return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'tags':tags})
    else:
        queryList = query.split(',')
        results = # Query the database to get results
        return render(request, 'search/results.html', {'query':query, 'results':results})
```

I have been searching for the best way to achieve this query in django

Also the results should be case intensive, plugging `TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True` into `settings.py` has not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code in your views:

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = request.GET['q'].split()  # I am assuming space separator in URL like "random stuff"

query = Q()
for word in q:
    query = query | Q(title__icontains=word) | Q(tags__name__icontains=word)
results = Post.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
def products_search(request):
    ''' If I am intending to use this in other places also ,I should better put this  in Model Manager'''
    query_original=request.GET.get('q',None)
    search_query = query_original.lower().split()
    if len(search_query)>=1:
        for word in search_query:
            lookups = Q(title__icontains=word) | Q(description__icontains=word) Q(tags__name__icontains=word)
    queryset     = Product.objects.filter(lookups,is_active=True).distinct() 
    context      = {'object_list':queryset}
    return render(request,'products/product_search.html',context)
```

Comment: Your `for loop` code is incorrect. It will only search for the last word in the list, since the variable `lookups` gets overwritten in each iteration. Also, no need to check length, you could just write: `if search_query:`